# How to search a file in program files folder using if not exists in batchfile

Tags: command-line, if-statement, batch-file

I am writing a batch file where I' m searching for a file like

`IF not exist "C:\Program Files\Bfsdfs\Fdsfsdfsde\dsfe.exe"`

and processing multiple statements in if else, but this statement always returns false, irrespective whether the file exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF not exist "C:\Program Files\Bfsdfs\Fdsfsdfsde\dsfe.exe" GOTO dosomething
@REM file found
...
GOTO :done

:dosomething
@REM file not found
...

:done
```

Comment: u mean to do me like
if not exist "C:\Program Files\Bfsdfs\Fdsfsdfsde\dsfe.exe" goto dosome
(
echo exefound
echo skipping installation
)

:dosomething
(
echo go ahead with after instalation steps
echo xxxx)
like this?

Comment: i got it the problem was i need to use the goto tab in if block to for skipping the else block to execute i done it